# Are there tools for fixing coil spring into its slots?

Tags: tools, timing-belt, springs, belt-tensioner, tensioner

I am trying to change the timing belt on my Hyundai Accent, and it has a thick coil spring that pushes the tensioner towards the belt. It is relatively easy to remove it, but putting it back can be hell. People recommend combinations of screw drivers and needle nose pliers but because of the high tension, they can slip and can scratch the surfaces around and eventually make dents in the sprocket which is a no-no situation.

My question is... is there any specific tool or a “safe” combinations of tools that can help bring that spring in its slots (see picture)? There must be tool for that, but I can’t really find it. Also, it has to fit in tight spaces.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! To clarify, you took *just the spring* portion of the tensioner out? Not the tensioner (spring and all) as a unit?

Comment: Thank you! I removed all the parts around that spring - the spring, the tensioner and the two bolts

Comment: It look like it may be possible to compress the spring before installation in a vice or clamp and then secure it with a large ZIP tie or other band-like product, install the spring, and then cut the band.  Hyundai probably calls for a special tool to install this which you won't have.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, butI have no vice and there is a lot of tension in it. Not sure that a zip tie would hold, but will try it. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Did you fit the tensioner before adding the belt?

Comment: Looks like a bolt hole in the block on the tensioner slot? Install a bolt there. Pry the tensioner back and tighten that bolt. Install belt and loosen the bolt. Rotate the engine a couple of times and recheck timing marks, then tighten the bolt.